# Posting data with json in xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, json, xcode

I'm creating an ios app with swift and part of it sends data to a remote web API via json (NSData) . It worked fine when I was using xcode 6 beta but after upgrading to xcode 6.0.1 it returns an error which I really can't understand.

I'm wondering if anybody can help me through this.

the Error is :

```
GeneralFunctions.swift:37:35: 'NSData?' does not have a member named 'length'
```

and my function is :

```
func sendData(req_url:String, data:String) -> String{
    let url = NSURL(string: req_url)
    let cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: cachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 2.0)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    let boundaryConstant = "----------V2ymHFg03esomerandomstuffhbqgZCaKO6jy";
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundaryConstant
    NSURLProtocol.setProperty(contentType, forKey: "Content-Type", inRequest: request)

    // set data
    var dataString = data
    let requestBodyData = (dataString as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    request.HTTPBody = requestBodyData

    // set content length
    NSURLProtocol.setProperty(requestBodyData.length, forKey: "Content-Length", inRequest: request)

    var response: NSURLResponse? = nil
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let reply = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

    let results = NSString(data:reply!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    //        println("API Response: \(results)")
    return results
}
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because requestBodyData does not have a property length because it is an optional that hasn't been taken out.

It should work Ii you do requestBodyData!.length instead of requestBodyData.length (adding the ! gets you the actual NSData object which does have a .length selector).

Read up on optionals: https://medium.com/@rrridges/swift-optionals-a10dcfd8aab5